# Making a NSPopUpButton display all my iCal Calendars.

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSPopUpButton and I want the Menu Items in it to display the users iCal calenders.
From there I want it depending on which is selected to change this code.

```
CalCalendar *calendar = [[store calendars] objectAtIndex:0];
```

The code defines which iCal calender to sync to, at the moment it's the default calender, however I want to change the calender to sync to depending on the Calender selected in the PopUp.

My Question : How do I make the NSPopUpButton display all the users iCal calenders and depending on which one is selected to change the calender to sync to? I'm currently just using the code above which sets it to the default one.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How do I make the NSPopUpButton display all the iCal calenders and depending on which one is selected to change the calender to sync too. I'm currently just using the code above which sets it to the default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fills an empty NSPopUpButton with the names of all iCal calendars:

```
for (CalCalendar* cal in [[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] calendars])
    [myPopUpButton addItemWithTitle:[cal title]];
```

Comment: Good that works. Now I thought of something, the Calenders are displayed in order, meaning `objectAtIndex:0` is the first in the list and so on. Could you not use `indexOfSelectedItem` on the NSPopUpButton to get the index of the selected one and then replace the 0 for `objectAtIndex:` with its result?